# How to move all element with class after an element with class

Tags: javascript, html

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sgnmb6uL/

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
  <div>
    <div class="hdr">
      Your Items
    </div>
    <div class="newIt item">
      item
    </div>
    <div class="newIt item">
      item
    </div>
    <div class="newIt item2">
      item2
    </div>
    <div class="newIt item">
      item
    </div>
    <div class="newIt item2">
      item2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I created a script which was able to add a new class from an already generated child div with the `newItem` class. I assigned `item` and `item2` depending on the text.

How can I now move all the element with `item2` class underneath `hdr` class using plain JS.

so finalized html looks like this:

```
<div class="main">
  <div>
    <div class="hdr">
      Your Items
    </div>
    <div class="newIt item2">
      item2
    </div>
    <div class="newIt item2">
      item2
    </div>
    <div class="newIt item">
      item
    </div>
    <div class="newIt item">
      item
    </div>
    <div class="newIt item">
      item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After selecting the `.hdr`, iterate over the `.item2`s and use `insertBefore` to put each of them after the `.hdr` (insert *before* the `.hdr`'s *next sibling*, which equates to inserting after the `.hdr`):

```js
const hdr = document.querySelector('.hdr');
const parent = hdr.parentElement;
document.querySelectorAll('.item2').forEach((item2) => {
  parent.insertBefore(item2, hdr.nextSibling);
});
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>
    <div class="hdr">
      Your Items
    </div>
    <div class="newIt item">
      item
    </div>
    <div class="newIt item">
      item
    </div>
    <div class="newIt item2">
      item2
    </div>
    <div class="newIt item">
      item
    </div>
    <div class="newIt item2">
      item2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To put the `.item2`s at the beginning of the parent instead, use `insertBefore` on the first child of the parent:

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('.main div');
document.querySelectorAll('.item2').forEach((item2) => {
  parent.insertBefore(item2, parent.children[0]);
});
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>
    <div class="newIt item">
      item
    </div>
    <div class="newIt item">
      item
    </div>
    <div class="newIt item2">
      item2
    </div>
    <div class="newIt item">
      item
    </div>
    <div class="newIt item2">
      item2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To retain the order, perhaps select the first non-`item2`, and `insertBefore` that element:

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('.main div');
const firstNonItem2 = parent.querySelector(':not(.item2)');
document.querySelectorAll('.item2').forEach((item2) => {
  parent.insertBefore(item2, firstNonItem2);
});
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>
    <div class="newIt item">
      item
    </div>
    <div class="newIt item">
      item
    </div>
    <div class="newIt item2">
      item2 first
    </div>
    <div class="newIt item">
      item
    </div>
    <div class="newIt item2">
      item2 second
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you also provide an example if the `.hdr` div wasn't there also please. Thank you.

Comment: How would you know where to insert them if the `.hdr` doesn't exist?

Comment: `item2` would be at the beginning inside the `div.main > div`

Comment: Then use `insertBefore` on the first child of `parent` instead of on the `.hdr`

Comment: Question though... let's say the `item2` I would like it to appear at the same order... is that possible?

Comment: Meaning if the text were different, when I am moving it up, I would like it to be in the same order at the top as it was in different places...

Comment: You could select the first non-item2 with `:not(.item2)`, and `insertBefore` that